# How can I create the loop properly while writing erosion filter?

Tags: c#, arrays, image-processing

I am trying to write an erosion filter.I tried determine the part that I changed but I wanna fill the other array elements as 255.How can I do that?

```
public static byte[] dnmmmerosion(byte[] data)
        {
            int wdth = 2400;
            int hght = 800;

            List<byte> dnmbytee = new List<byte>();

            byte[] dnmbyte = new byte[1200000];
            for (int i = 0; i < 1200000; i++)
            {
                dnmbytee[i] = 255;
            }   


            for (int k = 1; k < hght-1; k++)
            {
                for (int vvv = 0; vvv < wdth-1; vvv++)
                {
                    if (data[k+vvv] == 0 && data[k *wdth+vvv] == 0)
                    {
                        if (data[k * wdth + (vvv+1)] == 0 && data[k * wdth + vvv+2] == 0)
                        {
                            if (data[(k + 1) * wdth + vvv] == 0)
                            {
                                dnmbytee[k * wdth + vvv+1] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int zzz = 0; zzz < 1200000; zzz++)
            {
                dnmbyte[zzz] = dnmbytee[zzz];
            }

            return dnmbyte;
        }
```

I mean the elements that I fillled are above(like: data[k+vvv] == 0,...) and I guess I am making a mistake about coefficients while creating loops

PS:Ijust see a dull view when I write the code like that .

[image]

I am doing the processes on binary image.(So array consists of elements as 255 and 0.)If the elements of the structure same with the elements in image(for example elements:1,2,3,4,5) write 255 to the 3th element.

Comment: I’m not sure what the problem is. Please describe (or show) your output and your expected output.

Comment: Did you mean to write `data[k+vvv]`? Doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: I have a hard time about setting up the algorithm in code.I have a structure(I am gonna edit the code with structure.).I am actually trying to move the structure(I did not say matrix because I need some points in matrix).If any of the elements in array not different from the structure I am gonna changed the element of array as 0 otherwise I wanna make the value "0" but I could not write inside of the "for loop" properly.vvv is just a value like int i.I just wrote that for moving the structure as line.@Cris Luengo

Comment: I know that `vvv` is an integer variable. I'm wondering about `vvv + k`, rather than `vvv * width + k`. I don't think `vvv + k` makes sense as an index into the array. -- I'm still unclear what the problem is. Please describe why your code is not doing what you expect it to do. You describe what you want to accomplish, but not what your code actually does. Understanding the difference between what the code does and what you want it to do helps us pin-point the problem. I'm not going to run your code to find out what it does...

Comment: One obvious issue with your code is that you allocate 1,200,000 bytes, but access 2400x800 = 1,920,000 elements.

Comment: I wrote that as vvv+k because I need to move the first part of the structure pixel and pixel.If I got it as vvv*width +k I would be skipping the pixel up to width and my english is not good enough I guess I have hard time about explaining myself.Sorry about that.Finally 2400*500(height)=1200000 and this is a morphological filter(erosion).I am trying to implement it.@Cris Luengo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know C#, so won't be addressing some things I don't understand in the code.

First of all, you set

```
int wdth = 2400;
int hght = 800;
```

but then allocate 1,200,000 bytes for the output buffer. This means you loop over 2400 x 800 = 1,920,000 bytes, which is quite a bit beyond your buffer. I think you meant to set `hght = 500` instead. To avoid problems like this, don't use the same numerical value multiple times, instead define constants that you can use across your code:

```
int channels = 3;
int width = 800;   // let's not be lazy, and use real words as variable names!
int height = 500;
int buffer_size = channels * width * height;

byte[] dnmbyte = new byte[buffer_size];
for (int i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++)
...
```

Next, I'm unsure as to why you need the intermediate buffer `dnmbytee`, why you can't directly write into `dnmbyte`. Not knowing what a `List` is in C#, I'm assuming it's not an array, but an actual list data structure. This would be very expensive to use as you do, stick to arrays for pixel data!

Finally, the main problem: you are accessing the buffer as if you have 2400 x 500 pixels, each one a byte, rather than 800 x 500 pixels, each one three bytes (RGB). Morphological operations are not well defined on color images, so I will assume here that all three bytes for one pixel are always the same. If so, read the first byte of each pixel, and write all three bytes.

To do this, you would loop and index like this:

```
for (int y = 1; y < height-1; y++) {   // loop over all rows except the top and bottom-most ones
   for (int x = 1; x < width-1; x++) { // loop over all columns, except the left and right-most ones
      int current_pixel_index = (y * width + x) * channels;
      // read at data[current_pixel_index]
      ...
      dnmbyte[current_pixel_index + 0] = 0;
      dnmbyte[current_pixel_index + 1] = 0;
      dnmbyte[current_pixel_index + 2] = 0;
   }
}
```

To access neighboring pixels, you always add the same values to the current pixel index: `channels` to get the pixel to the right, `-width*channels` to get the pixel to the top, etc. Create a list for each pixel in your structuring element, then loop over this list:

```
int[5] neighbors;
neighbors[0] = -width*channels;
neighbors[1] = -channels;
neighbors[2] = 0;
neighbors[3] = +channels;
neighbors[4] = +width*channels;

for (int y = 1; y < height-1; y++) {
   for (int x = 1; x < width-1; x++) {
      int current_pixel_index = (y * width + x) * channels;
      for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
         // read at data[current_pixel_index + neighbors[k]]
      }
   }
}
```

The erosion logic can be like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
   if (data[current_pixel_index + neighbors[k]] == 0) {
      dnmbyte[current_pixel_index + 0] = 0;
      dnmbyte[current_pixel_index + 1] = 0;
      dnmbyte[current_pixel_index + 2] = 0;
      break;
   }
}
```

Since the output array was initialized to 255, if none of the neighbors are 0, it will remain at that value.

The code above does not set any of the pixels at the edge of the image (first and last row and column). If you want to process those as well, the easiest method is to pad the input by one pixel at all sides, the new pixels should have a value of 255. The alternative is to do special processing at the edge pixels, where you ensure you don't attempt to read out of bounds. That type of processing tends to slow code down a lot, and also complicates the code. Padding is usually worth it!

Comment: This answer is really comprehensive.Thank you for your answer.I am gonna try to write the code that you wrote.I am really appreciated and If you know any source for learning morphological image processing and share it would be great.@Cris Luengo

Comment: @stck_n I learned mathematical morphology from a book by Pierre Soille, though that book is quite outdated now, it doesn’t include any of the new advances in the field over the last 20 years or so. Also, a book like that doesn’t tech you to program it, it is more theoretical than that. I think I learned to program by doing it, and reading other people’s code, and collecting experience over time.

Comment: I understand.I really appreciated.Thank you.@ Cris Luengo